# Error - Can't execute in break mode - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, debugging

Thanks for everyone that answers questions on here. I use this site all the time. I'm not formally trained but have put together some stuff in the past. 
Here is what my Code accomplishes. I have a macro enabled excel file that I store in SharePoint. My users edit the excel and run a macro that saves their changes into a CSV File that we use to Import into JIRA.  I've been able to create the macro to do all this and it works great when I used it. But when others in my group use it they are getting a "Can't execute in break mode" error. I think I'm missing some validation code but I'm not sure how to achieve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm so close!!

```
'''
 Sub Save_CSV_Debugger()

 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

'Makes a copy of the Worksheet
 ws.Copy

'Creates New FileName - Concatenates username and Desktop path with for 
New Name
NewName = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\" & Range("A2").Value & " - 
JIRA Import" & ".CSV"

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'Saves WB with NewFileName
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=NewName, _
FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
'Hides saves dialog
If SaveAsUI = True Then Cancel = True

' Shows user a message

MsgBox "File saved to Desktop for JIRA Import " & vbNewLine & NewName

ActiveWorkbook.Close

'Reopens CSV File Without Macro - Clean CSV
Application.Workbooks.Open (NewName)

End Sub

'''
```

Comment: I have no idea what is happening here, but `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` might be masking some useful debugging information. You also seem to be decoding without the benefit of `Option Explicit`, either that, or you are using global variables defined elsewhere. I don't think that you have given enough information for others to see what the problem is. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: They are getting that error on one particular specific statement. Which one is it? ...and why would they be in break mode? I suspect your colleagues might be running that code with the wrong workbook active? There's a lot of implicit `ActiveSheet` voodoo going on here, it's entirely unclear from the code alone what instruction means to work against what workbook. Add `Debug.Assert Not ActiveWorkbook Is ThisWorkbook` just before the instruction that's blowing up: if execution stops, the assertion failed.

Comment: @JohnColeman Thanks for replying I've taken your suggestion and clean up the code a bit but my users are still getting the same error message. Any Sugguestions ?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - Thank you for shedding some light on my issue. I've clean up my code a little. My users are still getting the same issue. Any other suggestions? I tried to clean up the voodoo but on some level it got worse. it's the price to pay when you are hacking together code instead of being formally trained

Comment: You have two typos in your posted code which are syntax errors (The three lines which start with `New Name`). After I fix that the code runs without the error that you refer to. The line `If SaveAsUI = True Then Cancel = True` is problematic. For one thing, it suggests that you are coding without `Option Explicit` which is sort of like driving in bad weather without a seat belt. For another thing, if you run it without `Option Explicit` that line does nothing at all. Whatever the problem is, you haven't told us how to replicate it.